# Matter and antimatter

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, cipher

```
                 |
                 |
                 |
                 |
                 |
  \              |              /
   \             |             /
    \            |            /
     \           |           /
      \          |          /
       \         |         /
        \        |        /
         +-------+-------+
         |  FORESIGHT    |
         |   CONCEAL     |
         |  SIMILARLY    |
         |    TALENT     |
         |    SOLVER     |
         |     HEAVY     |
         |    SLAYING    |
         |   UNDULATED   |
         |     CAUSTIC   |
         |     BALANCE   |
         |    TONIGHT    |
         |     GUEST     |
         |   OPTION      |
         |  INSOLVENT    |
         |   CELLAR      |
         |    CALIBER    |
         | HATCHERY      |
         |    INCOMES    |
---------+   PLACATING   +---------
         |  FORGERY      |
         |     PAINTER   |
         |     SECTION   |
         |    THANK      |
         |     SUAVE     |
         |    LIMITING   |
         |     SHIELD    |
         |  MALLEABLE    |
         |    DISARMED   |
         |    HERMIT     |
         | PERFORATED    |
         |     ERUDITION |
         |     GAINFULLY |
         |     ASIDE     |
         |    DIVIDING   |
         |     WAIVER    |
         |    BEAUTIFUL  |
         |    HAZARD     |
         +-------+-------+
        /        |        \
       /         |         \
      /          |          \
     /           |           \
    /            |            \
   /             |             \
  /              |              \
                 |
                 |
                 |
                 |
                 |
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a solitude of the great rectangle of pipes, plus signs, and hyphens lies a list of words.

They are aligned in a staggered manner along a vertical bar which suggests they should be

> split into twin halves, as suggested by the title 'matter and antimatter'.

And so we try this and Now! we see a pattern!

The first word is FORESIGHT.

> We can insert a "T" along the center line, splitting it into "foresT" and "Tight".
>  Things look promising... continuing with the most likely words, the letters inserted begin to spell out a relevant message:
>  THE CENTER GET CE OF THE TWAIN BY THE MASSARDY.

> Okay, what is a Massardy?  All is not lost... there were a few choices for some of the words; lets try some other letters.  For example, the second S in Massardy was formed by 'asS' and 'Side'. Perhaps an H, 'asH' and 'Hide'?
>  Looking at the options, we find a few possible endings:
>  ...BY TH(E/O/S) MAS(S/H)(A/S)(R/G/D)DY
>  It appears likely we are looking for some piece of literature by Thomas... Haddy? Sardy?

> A bit of googling with the word 'Twain' and 'Thomas' brings us to the poem
>  The Convergence of the Twain by Thomas Hardy
>  And in fact, a trap had been laid (intentionally? by accident?). The most likely choices which led to the tantalizing word 'center' can be replaced with words that lead to 'convergence'.
>  Now we can fill the puzzle in full:

> [image: solution]

> Which gives our final answer read in bold down the middle:
>  "The Convergence of the Twain by Thomas Hardy"

> ...and thus, [consummation](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/47266/the-convergence-of-the-twain) comes, and jars two hemispheres.

Comment: Outstanding.  
The referenced text paints a fascinating image:  While the shipbuilders were busy constructing the Titanic in the shipyard, nature was busy elsewhere constructing the ship's "sinister mate", the iceberg.  Then, the two opposite twins were sent in equal but opposite directions toward each other.  And finally, the two halves collided in a singular event and became part of a singular whole.

Answer (score 1):

**Epilogue:**

Outstanding solution by @Amoz

Here is the image that inspired this puzzle:

> In all good science fiction movies, there is a scene where an object from the matter universe (white stars on black space) meets an object from the antimatter universe (black stars on white space) and like cancels like, resulting in an explosion.
>
>
>   Like this:
>
>
>      `FOREST          TIGHT`
>
>       `FOREST        TIGHT`
>
>        `FOREST      TIGHT`
>
>         `FOREST    TIGHT`
>
>          `FOREST  TIGHT`
>
>           `FORESTTIGHT`
>
>             `<boom!>`
>
>            `FORESIGHT`
>
>
>   The ASCII graphics are meant to depict the explosion and its aftermath.